# iOS: How to create an independent framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, shell, frameworks

I am creating a little SDK, I want to release a Foo.framework.
What I have done is the following:

1- Create a project framework.

2- Add my code.

3- Add an agregator.

In the Agregator Build Phases I added the this run script

```
#!/bin/sh
UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-universal
//make sure the output directory exists
mkdir -p "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}"
//Step 1. Build Device and Simulator versions
xcodebuild -target "${PROJECT_NAME}" ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphoneos  BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" clean build
xcodebuild -target "${PROJECT_NAME}" -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphonesimulator ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" clean build
//Step 2. Copy the framework structure (from iphoneos build) to the universal folder
cp -R "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework" "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/"
//Step 3. Create universal binary file using lipo and place the combined executable in the copied framework directory
lipo -create -output "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/${PROJECT_NAME}" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/${PROJECT_NAME}" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/${PROJECT_NAME}"
//Step 4. Convenience step to copy the framework to the project's directory
cp -R "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework" "${PROJECT_DIR}"
//Step 5. Convenience step to open the project's directory in Finder
open "${PROJECT_DIR}"
```

Then I build the Agregator and get the Foo.framwork
My problem is, to be able to use the framework in another application I should:

step 1 - drag and drop the framework to my project.

step 2- And add it to the embedded binaries.

If I don't do the step 2 I get this error

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Foo.framework/Foo
Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/00A2E4FD-23F4-43E8-AA85-505785A4FF16/foo.app/foo
Reason: image not found
```

How should I do if I want to use the framework only by dragging it to my project
(In other words add it only to Link Binary with Library) to make it simple to integrate.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For All People facing this kind of issue the solution is here.
Just follow those instruction to build a Framework

https://github.com/jverkoey/iOS-Framework#walkthrough